# Prove that no connected planar graph with $\lt 12$ faces and $\gt 3$ degree each vertex has a face with %\le 4$ bounding edges

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs

I've spent the last 7 hours trying to solve this one problem, no kidding. The textbook is absolutely useless and there's nothing helpful on the internet.

*Let $G$ be a simple plane graph with fewer than $12$ faces, in which each vertex has degree at least $3$. Use Euler's formula to prove that $G$ has a face bounded by at most four edges.*

Euler's Formula:

$$n - m + f = 2$$

So:

$$f \le 11$$
    For every vertex $v$, $deg(v) \ge 3$

So far I've figured out that I should probably prove (the contrapositive) that it's impossible for every face to be bounded by $\ge 5$ edges. In that case, there would be at least $5$ edges, and by extension, at least $5$ vertices. Also, the complete graph $K3$ has $4$ vertices and $8$ edges, so those are also minimums. Also that $5f \le 2m$, since each face is surrounded by $\ge 5$ edges and each edge is surrounded by $2$ faces.

Where do I go from there? I've covered 4 notebook pages in useless equations trying to work something out but have not made any progress at all.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every edge has two vertices, so the sum of the degrees of all vertices is $2m$. In particular, $2m \ge 3n.$

Therefore, $$2 = n - m + f \le -\frac{1}{3}m + f.$$

Every edge bounds two faces. So the sum of the number of edges bounding each face is also $2m$. If every face were bounded by at least five edges, then $5f \le 2m$. Together with the previous inequality, $$f \ge 2 + \frac{1}{3}m \ge 2 + \frac{5}{6}f,$$ or in other words $f \ge 12.$

Comment: Can you explain the steps in the 2nd inequality?

Comment: @ghert85 Replace $\frac{1}{3}m$ with $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{2} f$